# How to join tables with TypeORM?

Tags: join, left-join, nestjs, relational-database, typeorm

I have two tables: user and pet
My goal is to GET all active users active pets (active means enabled is true).
When I try to join those two tables to be able to filter active users I am getting 500 error.

I have used getRawMany and getMany, does not help.

```
@Entity({ name: 'pet' })
export class Pet {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: number;
  @Column()
  user_id: number;
  @Column()
  name: string;
  @Column()
  enabled: boolean;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.pets)
  user: User;
}

@Entity({ name: 'user' })
export class User {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  user_id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  enabled: boolean;

  @OneToMany(() => Pet, (pet) => pet.user)
  pets: Pet[];
}

// Service
async getActiveUsersActivePets(
    pageOptionsDto: PageOptionsDto,
    relations: string[] = [],
    throwsException = false,
  ): Promise<PageDto<Pet>> {
    const queryBuilder = this._petsRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('pet');

    queryBuilder
      .leftJoinAndSelect('pet.user', 'user')
      .where('enabled = :enabled', { enabled: true })
      .skip(pageOptionsDto.skip)
      .take(pageOptionsDto.take);

    const itemCount = await queryBuilder.getCount();
    const entities = await queryBuilder.getRawMany();

    const pageMetaDto = new PageMetaDto({ itemCount, pageOptionsDto });

    return new PageDto(entities, pageMetaDto);
  }
```

// Error

```
{
    "statusCode": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/api/v2/pets",
    "method": "GET",
    "timeStamp": "2022-04-28T13:53:18.863Z"
}
```

Comment: That `pets: Pet;` should be an array `pets: Pet[];`

Comment: @Youba thank you that you notice that, but after changes it does not help, still getting 500 error on GET request

Comment: Can you share the error message you get in the log on cli?

Comment: @Youba there is no error message in cli, only when I am using postman and doing request then I see the error
{
    "statusCode": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/api/v2/pets",
    "method": "GET",
    "timeStamp": "2022-04-28T13:53:18.863Z"
}